# Erro ao fazer join com Query Builder do Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, join, laravel-5.2

Estou fazendo o seguinte Join:

```
public function getStockDanger()
{
    $data = DB::table('product')
        ->join('stock', 'product.id', '=', 'stock.product_id')
        ->where('stock.stock', '<=', 0)
        ->get();

    return view(
        'product.index',
        [
            'data' => $data,
            'data_category' => $this->category->all(),
            'nav' => $this->nav
        ]
    );
}
```

View:

```
    @if($data->count() > 0)
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="id text-center">#</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Produto</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Quantidade</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Preço</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($data as $product)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="id text-center">{{$product->id}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a class="color-red"
                                                       href="/products/{{$product->id}}">{{$product->name}}</a></td>
                            <td class="text-center @if($product->stock->stock <= 0) credit_danger @else credit_ok @endif">{{$product->stock->stock}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center credit_ok">R$ {{$product->sale_price}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">
                                <a title="Editar" style="margin-right: 5px; color: #3498db; font-size: 18px;"
                                   href="/products/edit/{{$product->id}}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"
                                                                             aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <a title="Excluir" style="color: #e74c3c; font-size: 18px;"
                                   href="/products/delete/{{$product->id}}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                                                               aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                @include('pagination.default')
            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="alert alert-empty">
            <strong>Nenhum cadastro!</strong> Tabela vazia
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

Mas estou obtendo o seguinte erro

> FatalErrorException in ac3f490a3eb54420e99fe37a225e6f129d87f36d.php line 36:
>
> Call to a member function count() on a non-object

O que posso ter feito de errado?

Comment: Fica difícil descobrir sem a view. poste a linha 36 da view `product.index`.

Comment: Outra coisa: Sempre informe a versão do Laravel.

Comment: Erro na View linha 36?

Comment: Postei a view. Laravel 5.2

Comment: O problema parece ser que não está sendo reconhecido como objeto, mas como faço para vir uma coleção de objetos?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sua resposta não está errada. Larvel 5.2 ainda retorna um `array`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters deixe eu confirmar, teve tanta mudança que eu lembro que não retornava `class collection` ja volto ela!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O [**Query Builder**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) do [**Laravel 5.2**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/) não retorna uma [***class collection***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections) mas, um [***array***](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) simples, *olha o texto informativo em inglês*:

> Like raw queries, the get method returns an `array` of results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

### Então:

***altere essa linha***

```
@if($data->count() > 0)
```

***para essa***

```
@if(count($data) > 0)
```

Na versão Laravel 5.3 retorna um [***class collection***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-collections):

> The get method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP StdClass object. You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a property of the object:

Comment: Esse é outro problema, nessa view preciso manipular objetos, pois uso informaçoes de duas tabelas diferentes, uso o belongsTo pra conseguir puxar os atributos que estão em outra tabela, sabe se é possível fazer um join retornando uma collection de objetos no Laravel 5.2?

Comment: @FelipePaetzold se você configurou o Model, pode usar diretamente pelo classe de entidade, entendeu, essa mesma o traz os relacionamentos, você tem as classes configuradas?

Comment: Eu configurei os metodos acessores, mas eu preciso de uma parcela dos registros que atendem determinada condição, não de todos os registros, por isso preciso fazer o Join.

Comment: Quando você usa join com `Fluent Builder` ele não faz o jogo de relação igual o Eloquent, cada linha representa um campo da tabela e das relações, igual nos fazemos com um PDO ou Mysqli, cada linha represena a junção desse join, eu vi que você colocou `$product->stock->stock` isso não funciona mas, como você fez a relação ele deve estar em `$produto->nome_do_campo`. antes de enviar para tela dê um `var_dump($data)` no `Controller` verifica o que retorna essa é a solução final se vai entender rapidamente!

Comment: Na realidade ele me retorna uma collection, mas o join cria um atributo stock no objeto, entao nao consegui usar a mesma view, pois product->stock->stock nao existe ali, é product->stock... mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia fazer usando o Eloquent, dessa forma:

### Controller

```
public function getStockDanger()
{
    $data = Product::get();

    return view(
        'product.index',
        [
            'data' => $data,
            'data_category' => $this->category->all(),
            'nav' => $this->nav
        ]
    );
}
```

No **`Model Product`** você deveria ter um método de relacionamento:

```
class Product extends Model{
    public function stock(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Stock', 'product.id', 'product_id')->where('stock', '<=', 0);
    }
}
```

Daí na **View**...

```
@if($data->stock->count() > 0)
    @foreach($data->stock as $product)

        # Aqui pode deitar o pêlo.

    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Em versões anteriores ao Laravel 5.3, nenhum resultado de query do `Fluent` retorna `Collection`, e sim um `array`.

Como dito pelo Virgílio, use `count($data)` ao invés de `$data->count()`.

Apenas dando mais detalhes, Quando você usa `DB::table()`, você está usando o `Fluent`. Ele retornará `array`, diferentemente do `Eloquent`, que retorna um `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`.

Se você quiser evitar problemas ou até mesmo manter uma padronização no seu código, você pode usar `count($data)` tanto para `Eloquent` como para `Fluent`, uma vez que o `Collection` do Laravel implementa a interface `Countable` (quando você usa ela, é possível definir um comportamento para quando for chamado `count` na instância da classe).

Leia mais em:

- [Pra que serve a interface Countable no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157367/pra-que-serve-a-interface-countable-no-php)