# Pra que serve a interface Countable no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface, count

Vi uma determinada classe cuja declaração estava dessa forma:

```
class Collection implements Countable {}
```

Percebi que ela estava implementando `Countable`, mas não entendi o que essa implementação estava fazendo lá.

Qual é a  finalidade de `Countable`? Isso é uma interface padrão do PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, é [uma interface padrão](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) do PHP. Serve para tornar um objeto compatível com a função [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php). Se a sua classe implementa `Countable` e possui um método `count`, esse método será invocado quando uma instância da classe for passada para a função `count` global do PHP.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php
class Lista implements Countable {

    private $items = [];
    private $total = 0;

    public function add($item) {
        array_push($this->items, $item);
        $this->total++;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->total;
    }
}

$lista = new Lista();
$lista->add(1);
$lista->add('foo');

var_dump(count($lista)); // 2
```

Answer (score 4):

[Conforme a documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) é para obrigar a implementação do método `Count()`. É usada em classes de coleções de dados que precisam de forma padronizada de obter a contagem de todos itens contidos nela.

Em geral espera-se que a complexidade ela seja O(1), mas não é obrigado, e para isso a estratégia mais adotada é guardar a contagem do objeto em algum membro e qualquer alteração nela já ser refletida nesse contador.

Cada classe pode implementar como quiser o mecanismo desde que a API conforme com a interface.

Comment: Meu exemplo então não foi bom, porque é O(n) -- acho.

Comment: @bfavaretto idealmente não é bom mesmo, mas não impede de usar. Como eu disse pode fazer como achar melhor. Apenas que o normal, em linguagens decentes :D se espera que o programador faça O(1), mas não é requisito.

Comment: Troquei meu exemplo para uma implementação O(1) :-)

Comment: @bfavaretto na verdade não sei se aquela forma é O(N), eu acho que ela faz o mesmo que você está fazendo. Posso estar enganado, mas tudo que o `count()` da linguagem aceita para contar deve ter a contagem armazenada

Comment: Capaz mesmo. Mas considerando as "boas práticas" que você citou, achei melhor deixar um exemplo que cuida da própria contagem.

Comment: Eu tinha esquecido do +1 :p